# How to show error message in Magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm developing Magento 2 extension. I've added controller_action_predispatch_checkout event observer and trying to add a error message via ManagerInterface.

events.xml:

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout">
    <observer name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout" instance="<namespace>\<module>\Observer\CheckoutPredispatchObserver" />
</event>
```

CheckoutPredispatchObserver.php:

```
class CheckoutPredispatchObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

private $messageManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager) {
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;        
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Custom error message");
}

}
```

**However, my error message is not displayed in checkout page:**

[image: Checkout page]

**Instead, I can see my error message twice in checkout success page:**
[image: Checkout success page]

> How can I make my error message appear in Checkout page but not in
>   further pages?

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this event

**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
    ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
);
```

These are all checkout events

**1) checkout_directpost_placeOrder**

```
$this->eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_directpost_placeOrder',
    [
        'result' => $result,
        'action' => $this
    ]);
```

**2) checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
    ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]);
```

**3) checkout_cart_update_item_complete**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_update_item_complete',
    ['item' => $item, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]);
```

**4) checkout_controller_onepage_saveOrder**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_controller_onepage_saveOrder',
    [
'result' => $result,
'action' => $this
    ]);
```

**5) checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
    ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]);
```

**6) checkout_allow_guest**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_allow_guest',
    ['quote' => $quote, 'store' => $store, 'result' => $result]);
```

**7) checkout_cart_product_add_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
    ['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]);
```

**8) checkout_cart_update_items_before**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_update_items_before',
    ['cart' => $this, 'info' => $infoDataObject]);
```

**9) checkout_cart_update_items_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_cart_update_items_after',
    ['cart' => $this, 'info' => $infoDataObject]);
```

**10) checkout_cart_save_before**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_before', ['cart' => $this]);
```

**11) checkout_cart_save_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_after', ['cart' => $this]);
```

**12) checkout_cart_product_update_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
'checkout_cart_product_update_after',
['quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product]);
```

**13) custom_quote_process**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('custom_quote_process', ['checkout_session' => $this]);
```

**14) checkout_quote_init**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_quote_init', ['quote' => $quote]);
```

**15) load_customer_quote_before**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('load_customer_quote_before', ['checkout_session' => $this]);
```

**16) checkout_quote_destroy**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_quote_destroy', ['quote' => $this->getQuote()]);
```

**17) restore_quote**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('restore_quote', ['order' => $order, 'quote' => $quote]);
```

**18) checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
'checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
['order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote()]);
```

**19) checkout_submit_all_after**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'checkout_submit_all_after',
    [
'order' => $order,
'quote' => $this->getQuote()
    ]);
```

**20) checkout_multishipping_refund_all**

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_multishipping_refund_all', ['orders' => $orders]);
```

Comment: The event you suggested (checkout_onepage_controller_success_action) fired before rendering success page. But I need to show my message in Checkout page (/magento/checkout), not in (/checkout/onepage/success).